# Parameters for generate:entity command in Symfony 3

Tags: command, entity, symfony

I would like to run a command into my custom command.
But I don’t know how to pass the `--no-interaction` parameter for this command into my code.

```
$command = $this->getApplication()->find('generate:doctrine:entity');

        $arguments = array(                
            '--entity'=>'TestBundle:Fruit',
            '--format'=>'yml',
            '--fields'=>'Nom:string  Couleur:string Prix:decimal PaysOrigine:String',
            '--no-interaction'=>true
        );

        $input = new ArrayInput($arguments);
        $returnCode = $command->run($input, $output);
```

But that still open my console to have some interaction. Can someone help me?

Answer (score 0):

I finally found a way. just add:
$input->setInteractive(false);

```
$command = $this->getApplication()->find('generate:doctrine:entity');

        $arguments = array(
            '--entity' => 'TestBundle:Fruit',
            '--fields' => 'Nom:string  Couleur:string Prix:float PaysOrigine:String',
            '--format' => 'yml'
        );

        $input = new ArrayInput($arguments);
        $input->setInteractive(false);
        $command->run($input, $output);
```